# Piecewise orthogonal regression

Tags: regression, python, piecewise-linear

I want to fit data points by linear segments. The summed squared orthogonal distance of the points to the fitting lines shall be minimized, preferably using weights for the data points and for a wished number of breakpoints. How could this be implemented? Is there a solution in Python?

I am aware of the [piecewise OLS regression](https://github.com/chasmani/piecewise-regression) package for python however this is not suitable as the error is minimized only along one direction. Also there is an [orthogonal regression](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) function in scipy but no piecewise fitting.

Comment: Are the segments fixed length, or variable? How many data points do you have?. Note that fitting a dataset with $m$ linear segments where the segment breaks are at specified locations is an $m+1$ parameter model. If the intervals are also fit, then it is a $2m$ parameter model. Either way, it will be an *expensive* model in the sense of increased generalization error. I hope you have enough data to pay the cost: $\mathcal{O}(10)$ independent data points per fit-able parameter. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_in_ten_rule).

Comment: The breaking points the algorithm shall find, I just define their number.